# Disable Checkbox (LVITEM) in the CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have my own implementation of `CListCtrl` with checkboxes (`LVITEM`) and their sub-items. I can make sub-items **disabled** but I don't know how to disable **checkboxes**.

How do I make disabled **greyed** items in `CListCtrl` when the item is `LVITEM`?

Comment: Show at least some code, otherwise your question is unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no status for a disabled checkbox.

But you can prevent the status change in `LVN_ITEMCHANGING`. This notification is sent before any changes to the list view are applied.

```
void CWzProjectStatistic_User::OnItemchangingLcData(NMHDR* pNMHDR,LRESULT* pResult) 
{
  LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV= reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

  // clear result (accept changes)
  *pResult = 0;

  // Only if the state changes
  if ((pNMLV->uNewState&LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK)!=(pNMLV->uOldState&LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK))
  {
    if (IfThisIsADisabledEntry(pMLV))
      *pResult = 1;
```

There is also a chance to implement your own graphic and checkbox handling. You may assign your own imagelist to the list view and you can use your own handling  of the state images with `LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK` and `INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK`

Comment: _implement your own graphic and checkbox handling_ - That's what I would do (and have done). The only tricky part is to create the image list for the checkbox states (to match the current theme). This can be done using `GetThemePartSize()` and `DrawThemeBackground()` with `iPartId` of `BP_CHECKBOX` and `iStateId` of `CBS_...`. If you need to support Windows versions older than Win 8, there is `DrawFrameControl()` for the "classic" look.